# Unable to launch Selenium Serenity tests on Firefox or Safari due to net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I am trying to launch Serenity Selenium tests on firefox and safari. The tests works with Chrrome however, when launched using firefox I notice error - net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.

Sample code:

```
@Test
public void shouldDisplayHighlightedProductsOnTheWelcomePage() {
    login.as(User.STANDARD_USER);

    List<String> productsOnDisplay = productList.titles();

    assertThat(productsOnDisplay).hasSize(6)
            .contains("Sauce Labs Backpack");
}

serenity.conf looks like this:

    serenity.test.root=serenityswag
    webdriver.driver=firefox
    serenity.take.screenshots=BEFORE_AND_AFTER_EACH_STEP
    serenity.browser.maximized = true
```

Loginactions.java looks like this:

```
public class LoginActions extends UIInteractionSteps {
    @Step("Log in as {0}")
    public void as(User user) {
        openUrl("https://www.saucedemo.com/");

        // Login as a standard user
        $("[data-test='username']").sendKeys(user.getUsername());
        $("[data-test='password']").sendKeys(user.getPassword());
        $("[data-test='login-button']").click();
    }

The error I see is following:

    net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
    WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
    See below for more details.
    
        at serenityswag.authentication.actions.LoginActions.as(LoginActions.java:10)
        at serenityswag.inventory.WhenViewingHighlightedProducts.shouldDisplayHighlightedProductsOnTheWelcomePage(WhenViewingHighlightedProducts.java:32)
    
    07:39:39.688 [main] ERROR  - 
      _____   ___   ___   _____     ___   ___   ___    ___    ___ 
     |_   _| | __| / __| |_   _|   | __| | _ \ | _ \  / _ \  | _ \
       | |   | _|  \__ \   | |     | _|  |   / |   / | (_) | |   /
       |_|   |___| |___/   |_|     |___| |_|_\ |_|_\  \___/  |_|_\
    
    Should display highlighted products on the welcome page
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    07:39:39.691 [main] DEBUG  - RELATED ISSUES: 
    07:39:39.760 [main] ERROR  -     Test failed at step: Log in as a standard user
    07:39:39.760 [main] ERROR  -     Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the firefox browser resolved by removing the geckodriver from /usr/local/bin/geckodriver.

The issue with safari browser resolved once Allow Remote Automation enabled from the develop menu